# Add string inputs into an array

Tags: array

I have been working on this a while and I cannot seem to figure it out. Essentially, I am using the app/server Blynk and their Terminal Widget to sent String inputs to my Arduino board. My code is below:

  `String INFO;
  String fromTerminal = param.asStr();
  int indexstart = fromTerminal.indexOf(",");
  int indexend = fromTerminal.lastIndexOf(",");
  int counter = indexstart - indexend;
  INFO[counter] = fromTerminal;`

My thoughts on the code was, based on the number of "," I enter in the string then that will assign my input to an index within the INFO array. However as I have tried several different things, I constantly get errors such as:
cannot convert 'String' to 'char' in assignment.
Oddly enough if I set: INFO[counter] = fromTerminal.toInt();
I dont get an error but I dont think that will allow me to print out my actual input. Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `INFO` isn't an array - it's a String.

Comment: Yeah so I was looking into it further, dumb oversight on my part but I guess you cant dynamically create an array. So I am just going to over initialize the array ie. INFO[20}; even when I only ever input between 5-10 strings, and then just call the index up to how many I input

Answer (score 1):

I think you should better read about the [String Object](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringObject) and don't mix this up with [string as char array](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/String).

Comment: That is not an answer!